# How does a queue knows a thread is done without task_done() specified?

Tags: python, multithreading, queue

I'm doing some threads expirements, and noticed that my code works **even without q.task_done()** statement.

```
import Queue, threading

queue = Queue.Queue()

def get_url(url):
    queue.put({url: len(urllib2.urlopen(url).read())})

def read_from_queue():
    m = queue.get()
    print m.items()
    queue.task_done()  # <-- this can be removed and still works

def use_threads():
     threads = []
     for u in urls:
         t = threading.Thread(target=get_url, args=(u,))
         threads.append(t)
         t.start()

     for t in threads:
         t.join()

     threads = []
     for r in urls:
         t = threading.Thread(target=read_from_queue)
         threads.append(t)
         t.start()

     for t in threads:
         t.join()
```

This is a simple program that loops over list of urls, reading their content and sums it up to the len of bytes. It then puts in the queue a dict containing the url name and its size.

I have `timeit.timeit` tested both cases; the results are mixed but that make sense because most of the work happens on network.

How the **queue** knows a task is done? How the `t.join()` returns without `task_done()` is being called on the queue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`queue.task_done` only affect `queue.join`

`queue.task_done` doesn't affect `thread.join`

You are calling `thread.join` and never call `queue.join`, so `queue.task_done` doesn't matter

Comment: I just read it on the docs, updated my answer. Doing some tests, you may be right in the point that I `join` threads and not the queue.

Answer (score 0):

**Zang MingJie** got it right. I was `join()` the threads, not the queue itself.
When the threads complete, the `join()` returns.

That's the piece I was missing:

The whole idea of `task_done()` is *when the threads are daemons, or never returns until killed*. Then you can't `join()` the threads, because it will deadlock.

So, when you have such a scenario - you `join()` the queue. This will return when the queue is empty of tasks (indicating there is currently no more work).